# React.JS / Next.JS NODE_ENV=production runtime error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, production-environment, next.js13, nodeenv

I `yarn install`, `yarn build`, build the docker image, deploy to EKS and hit the following runtime error:

```
NODE_ENV: production
(node:1) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
    at process.binding (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:140:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/http-deceiver/lib/deceiver.js:22:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/spdy/lib/spdy/handle.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
    at process.binding (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:140:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/http-deceiver/lib/deceiver.js:22:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/spdy/lib/spdy/handle.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
warn  - You have enabled experimental features (forceSwcTransforms, swcTraceProfiling, externalDir, appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:198
                throw new Error(`Could not find a production build in the '${this.distDir}' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id`);
                      ^

Error: Could not find a production build in the '/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:198:23)
    at new Server (/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:68:29)
    at new NextNodeServer (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:70:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:147:16)
    at async /node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:159:31
    at async NextServer.prepare (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:134:24)

Node.js v19.9.0
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `ADD .next .next` to Dockerfile

Comment: ...how would that help?